# How to position a video to the center in media queries (iPhone)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I currently have a youtube video placed with this code.  The problem is that the margin-left creates a 65px white border on the right of the page. I've tried with setting it to `position:absolute`. Then I used `top: left: %` to adjust position, but that makes the entire page very different when changing the resolution just a bit.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 200px) and (max-device-width : 1099px) {
 .video {
    position    : static;
    width       : 100%;
    height      : auto;
    float       : none;
    margin-left : 65px;
}
}
```

Comment: can you update more code

Comment: wrap it in a <div> and use `{margin: 0 auto}` on that <div>

Comment: Why do you keep the left margin if you want to position it in the middle?

Comment: you can set video width 100%; then how can the video center ,it full width i tihnk

Comment: Well the .video is the div class and by adding {margin: 0 auto} i just remove the margin left and the image is not centered anymore.

Comment: without margin-left the video is aligned to the left , the 65px make the video centered but created the white border on the right.

Comment: can you show a fiddle or working link

Comment: Well i really have no idea how to make a fiddle when the problem is on iphone resolutions and the css is for a media querie.

Comment: That's not an issue, just add the relevant CSS and html to the fiddle, browsers have dev tools that allow you to see what the website looks like on a phone - even if you're using a PC. if you put the correct css and html elements - including the media query rule - we will be able to see the issue.  Otherwise, you can post a link to the page that has the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to use `margin: 0 auto` (which I highly suggest), you can use the `calc()` function within CSS on `left`, whilst using `position: relative` to center it.

Like so:

```
.video{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: calc(50% - 100px); // the negative amount MUST be half of the actual video element
    width: 200px; // in this example, it is 200px, so the negative value must be 100px
}
```

Good thing is, relative positioning will allow thew rest of your website elements to stay the same, without any de-positioning.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This worked in a bit different way but it worked!! after some modification this made the video centered with everything working properly.

Comment: .utubemission {
   position: relative;
     top: 0px;
     left: calc(50% - 545px); // 
     width: 960px;
 }

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use and it's also responsive

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flexible-container iframe,
.flexible-container object,
.flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://b922bde52f23a8481830-83cb7d8d544f653b52d1a1621f05ea9d.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/video/landingpage.mp4" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```